# PyQt: Import .xls file and populate QTableWidget?

Tags: python, pyqt, xls, qtablewidget

How can I import an .xls file using Python and PyQt and then populate a QTableWidget with it's contents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use [xlrd](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlrd) for reading and writing .xls files examples [here](http://www.numbergrinder.com/2008/10/pulling-data-from-excel-using-python-xlrd/) and [here](http://scienceoss.com/read-excel-files-from-python/)

Comment: I don't know which one is best but for my projects xlrd have been promising

Answer (score 1):

try my library `pyexcel`,

Suppose you have a csv, xls, xlsx file as the following:

```
1,2,3
4,5,6
7,8,9
```

The following code will give you the data in json

```
from pyexcel as pe
import json

# "example.xls", please import pyexel.ext.xls
# "example.xlsx", please import pyexcel.ext.xlsx
# "example.ods", please import pyexcel.ext.ods or pyexcel.ext.ods3
sheet= pe.load("example.csv")
print json.dumps(sheet.to_array())
```

The output is:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

You can easily initialize `QTableWidiget(sheet.number_of_rows(), sheet.number_of_columns())` and then fill in the table widget with the array, `data`.

More code examples can be found in this page: https://github.com/chfw/pyexcel

API documentation can be found here: http://pyexcel.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html

Comment: Hey pal, kind of late, but nice answer anyway... :)

Answer (score 0):

For importing and reading the .xls file, I would start with [xlutils](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlutils), specifically xlrd